# Manually input different values for each row in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So, I basically have a matrix with several columns, all of which are expressions based on the numbers in column A. The numbers in column A are each unique, but will remain the same and don't need to be refreshed. So, what I want to do is to create a matrix that looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <TR>
    <TH>Column A</TH>
    <TH>Column B</TH>
    <TH>Column C</TH>
    <TH>Column D</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>31</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>123</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>75</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>98</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
    <TD>Epxression</TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

I.e., having manually inputted static values in column A, with everything else as an expression based on those values. I've tried a few solutions using parameters and such, but haven't had any luck. Is what I want to do possible in SSRS?

Note: Unfortunately I'm not able to input the values into the original SQL table.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more; this question feels incomplete as is.

Comment: Why can these static values not be included in your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant but if I understand your question correctly then you could use a single parameter to type the values in (comma separated).

You would then need to use a split function (as SPLIT_STRING was only introduced in SQL2016). I use one that can be found towards the end of this article as it is very fast.. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

So your dataset query would look something like this.

```
SELECT ItemNumber as [SortOrder], Item as [ColumnA] FROM DelimitedSplit8k(@myParameter, ',')
```

So your dataset output, assuming you typed `31,123,75,98` into your parameter will look like the table below (based on your example)

```
SortOrder    ColumnA
    1        31
    2        123
    3        75
    4        98
```

You can then just add a a table bound tothis dataset, add [ColumnA] as the first column and your expressions in the other three columns.